# Unnecessary use of extern within implementation file?

Tags: c

Say we have a header in a C library that refers to an `extern` variable:

*a.h:*

```
extern const struct foo f;
```

And in an implementation file of the library, we find the definition of `f`:

*impl.c:*

```
extern const struct foo f; // Is this `extern` really necessary?

static const struct foo *array[] = {
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &f,
    NULL
};

const struct foo f = { "alpha", array + 1 };
```

You'll notice that the declaration of `f` is first, so that `array` can refer to it, which also has to precede the definition of `f` at the bottom, which refers to `array`.

Regardless, isn't the use of `extern` in *impl.c* pointless, since the definition exists within this same file? Would removing the `extern` from the  declaration of `f` in *impl.c* affect those using this library via *a.h*? Running an ABI check shows me no difference before and after removing the `extern` attribute in *impl.c*. Is there any benefit to keeping the `extern` there, perhaps indicating to readers of *impl.c* that `f` is intended to be shared globally, in addition to being defined/initialized below?

Comment: No, the `extern` declaration in the implementation file is unnecessary but harmless.  Of course, `impl.c` should include `a.h` so that the necessary cross-checking is in place.  That way, all the files that include `a.h` — both the implementor and the consumers — can be sure they're using the same declaration, which minimizes the chances for things to go astray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to answer is to just go and test it.

The result is - if there is no first declaration of `f`, you get a compilation error - symbol `f` is not defined when you are initializing `array`. So the difference is just between `struct foo f` and `extern struct foo f`. And there is a slight difference actually - how it is placed into data segment.

This is probably implementation defined, but when I use gcc, using `extern struct foo f` in first declaration places `f` after `array`, while without `extern` it goes in front of it.

Or you can simply `#include "a.h"` and have the same `extern struct foo f`  added to `impl.c` by preprocessor.

Comment: The "Or you can simply `#include "a.h"` …" should be upgraded to a much stronger statement: "But you should (there are no excuses not to) `#include "a.h"` …".

Comment: But you picked up a valid point — the declaration is necessary before the definition because of the reference to `f` before it is defined.

Comment: Despite the principles involved, the recommendation to "just test it" is important. In my case, removing these issues indeed causes errors by consumers of the library.

Answer (score 1):

> Unnecessary use of `extern` within implementation file?

Perhaps it has some arcane value - I see it as redundant and should be removed form the top of the .c file

> Regardless, isn't the use of extern in *impl.c* pointless, since the definition exists within this same file?

The `extern const struct foo f;` in *impl.c* is not needed.  It may have value considering the larger layout of code and therefore have some documentation value.

> Would removing the extern from the declaration of `f` in *impl.c* affect those using this library via *a.h*?

No, not as things are currently coded.

> Is there any benefit to keeping the extern there, perhaps indicating to readers of impl.c that f is intended to be shared globally, in addition to being defined/initialized below?

Only a bit as that would be the usual usage of the unnecessary declaration. It may be the result of an evolved set of code.

---

What I find problematic is the naming style of `a.h`, `f` and `impl.c` which has not hint of correlation - of course that may be OP's simplification of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring it in `a.h`, you are already indicating that it should be shared globally.

Instead, `extern` is used to indicate that the value is coming from an external location. So, it is pretty pointless when the value is defined in the same file.